# Python- Is number pronic and if not find nearest pronic number

Tags: python

The task is for some input number to find out is that number pronic and if not to find nearest pronic number to entered number. The question is how to write the rest of the code. I managed to do the first part and find out is the entered number pronic or not. The problem is I can't find good way to find the nearest larger number if entered number is not pronic. I had an idea to add into else part nested for loop that finds all the pronic numbers from 1 to n, append them to the list and find the max of that list but even if I do that I would only find nearest smaller number, not the nearest that could also be larger than given number. For now, I have:

```
flag=0
n=int(input('Enter the number: '))
for i in range(1,n):
    if i*(i+1)==n:
        flag=1
if flag==1:
    print('Entered number is pronic!')
else:
    def pro(n):
        flag=False
        for j in range(1,n):
            if j*(j+1)==n:
                flag=True
                break
        return flag
list1=[]
for i in range(1,n):
    if pro(i):
        list1.append(i)
print('Not pronic. Closest smaller pronic number: ',max(list1))
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? Please edit your answer to include a problem statement. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: The question is how to write the rest of the code. I managed to do the first part and find out is the entered number pronic or not. The problem is I can't find good way to find the nearest larger or smaller number if entered number is not pronic. I had an idea to add into else part nested for loop that finds all the pronic numbers from 1 to n, append them to the list and find the max of that list but even if I do that I would only find nearest smaller number, not the nearest that could also be larger than given number.

Comment: Please edit your original question to include this new information.

Comment: this sounds a lot like a homework question, is the aim to learn about loops or why aren't you using the relation given in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronic_number)?

Comment: as @SamMason hinted: if the aim is to learn about loops, just insist, and you will find the answer. If, OTOH, the aim is to find a smarter idea, the Wikipedia page should be enough. If it isn't, just consider that the two numbers a pronic number is the product of, cannot be far from the square root of the number – they must be very close indeed...

Comment: I edited the code so you can see my idea. I just don't have the idea to find closest larger or smaller number except to try n+1 and n-1 but I don't have enough experience to finish it till the end. I'm little embarrassed but I'm working whole day to get to this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when trying to solve problems with code, you're better off reusing code other people have written to solve similar problems.  finding "similar" problems can be difficult in the beginning, but quickly gets easier with practice!

in this case, I'd exploit the fact that "pronic numbers" are defined to be "the product of two consecutive integers".  using your variable names, we can turn this into the optimisation problem: find the integer `i` where `i*(i+1)` is closest to `n`.

I'd first notice that `i*(i+1)` looks a lot like `i*i`, and this is inverted by taking the square root.  computers can find square roots very easily, so `sqrt(n)` will be a good starting point in looking for `i`

trying this with a few numbers:

```
 n sqrt(n) nearest  i
 6   ~2.4     6     2
 7   ~2.6     6     2
 8   ~2.8     6     2
 9    3.0    12     3
11   ~3.3    12     3
12   ~3.5    12     3
```

we can see that the fractional part of `sqrt(n)` also gives us information about the "nearest" pronic number: <0.5 means we need a smaller number, >0.5 means we need a larger one, which is similar to "rounding" a number.  we can also see that the `i` used to get the nearest number is just the integer part of the `sqrt`

moving to Python code, we can do:

```
from math import sqrt

def nearest_pronic(n):
  i = int(sqrt(n))
  return i * (i+1)
```

which you can use however you like, e.g:

```
n = float(input('give me a number'))
np = nearest_pronic(n)
if n == np:
  print(f"{n} is a pronic number")
else:
  print(f"the nearest pronic number to {n} is {np}")
```

which does the right thing for me.